# How do I center a navigation bar that is only part of the page width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a navigation bar on my website. The difficulty I am having is that I do not want the navigation bar's width to take up the entire page width and I want the position of the navigation bar to be fixed.

Here's a very simple example of what I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/de83m2zL/51/

As you can see, the navigation bar is only part of the page width, but isn't centered. My question is, how can I make it centered?

```css
div#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #0050ca;
}

div ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div ul li a {
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<br>

<h1>
  Hello!
</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
div#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #0050ca;
}
```

You can position it at 50% of the screen using `left: 50%` and then

translate the whole element of *-50% of its own width* using `transform: translateX(-50%)`

---

**Note:** You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005682/how-to-compensate-for-left-top-bottom-right-in-css#answer-37006310) to have a pictured view of how it works.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I'm a little curious — if I'm just positioning the element 50% to the left and then moving it back, why is the outcome different from not positioning it at all?

Comment: `left: 50%` position the element to 50% of the width of the screen and `transform: translateX(-50%)` just slide the element to 50% of the element width (its screen width vs element width)

Comment: @Gravitron I edited my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what you want to center, but:

1.) If you want to center the `li` items inside the (blue)  `ul` , use `text-align-center;` on the `ul`

2.) If you want to center the fixed, 80% wide `ul` on the page, use left and right margins of 10% (= half of 100% page width minus 80% width of `ul`):

```css
div#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 10%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #0050ca;
  
}

div ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

div ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div ul li a{
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<br>

<h1>
Hello!
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have clarified that I want to center the blue box, but that works.